# What is the fastest way to merge similar uv islands

Tags: texturing, uv

I've just started uv unwrapping a simple object in Blender and am trying to get more useable texture resolution by using the same uvs for multiple similar uv islands (in this case, the mesh is simple, so the islands I want to merge are single polygons). Although I can manually flip the top uv island and move it onto the similar one below, I was wondering if there is a quicker, *preferably* automated way ***that works with more complicated uv islands***

(sorry my example is so simple... imagine more complex islands).

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [UV Align\Distribute addon](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?340206-Add-On-UV-Align-Distribute) which will do what you want.

[image]

Here is how to use it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=clgrf0DUvso

Comment: I think I saw this video a while back and totally forgot about it. Looks like it does what I want - there is some manual work involved, but it's close enough. Also, Blender 2.73 has a new select similar features tool, so perhaps this will further speed up UV unwrapping.